# System Idle Time calculation using vc++

Tags: vb.net, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I need to get the sytem idle time.It must be developed in vc++ and the code should not use hooks is there any possible way of getting SystemIdleTime from taskmanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=system+idle+time+windows+c%2B%2B&btnG=Search) to rescue.